# Adding static view to coordinator layout

Tags: android, layout, view, static

I am building an app using the new coordinator layout, I followed the example shown here http://saulmm.github.io/mastering-coordinator about the Custom Behaviors. I successfully implemented the example in my code, but now i want to add another static view under the toolbar, this view should scroll along the toolbar at all times. I cant seem to make it work so i was hopeful someone here might enlighten me on the matter.

here is my xml as of now

```
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/main.appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        >

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/main.collapsing"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/main.imageview.placeholder"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/login_background_2"
                android:tint="#11000000"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.9"
                />

            <FrameLayout
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.3"

                >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/main.linearlayout.title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:gravity="bottom|center"
                        android:text="groupname"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="30sp"
                        />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                        android:text="group asda"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        />

                </LinearLayout>
            </FrameLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
           >
        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/main.toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/frameLayout"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
        app:title=""
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
            <Space
                android:layout_width="@dimen/image_final_width"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/image_final_width"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/main.textview.title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:text="afdfadfadf"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:layout_width="@dimen/image_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/image_width"
        android:src="@drawable/extension_mascot"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        app:layout_behavior="AvatarImageBehavior"
        app:finalYPosition="2dp"
        app:finalHeight="@dimen/image_final_width"
        android:id="@+id/groupMascot"
        app:startToolbarPosition="2dp"
        app:startHeight="2dp"
        app:startXPosition="2dp"
        />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

any ideas of how this should be done? 
what I want to add below the toolbar is a linearlayout with 3 text fields that take up the whole width and divide among them.
any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I made the same example and resolved the problem adding the reoursce file to the values folder, the file name is attrs.xml and looks like that:

```
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="AvatarImageBehavior">
        <attr name="finalYPosition" format="dimension"/>
        <attr name="startXPosition" format="dimension"/>
        <attr name="startToolbarPosition" format="dimension"/>
        <attr name="startHeight" format="dimension"/>
        <attr name="finalHeight" format="dimension"/>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

That resolve me for me the problem